# Received status code 400 from server: Invalid maven-metadata.xml during publishing artifacts to maven2

Tags: maven, nexus

I am trying to upload jar artifacts to Nexus repository (maven2 snapshot) and next error is received:

> Could not PUT 'http://{path-to-repository}/1.1-snapshot/maven-metadata.xml': Received status code 400 from server: Invalid maven-metadata.xml GAV ..., 1.1-snapshot does not match request path 1.1-snapshot/maven-metadata.xml

I am using **maven-publish** plugin from Gradle script. I have provided code snippet below

```
afterEvaluate {
    project -> {
        publishing {
            publications {
                maven(MavenPublication) {
                    groupId = 'org.company'
                    version = '1.1-snapshot'

                    from components.java
                }
            }

            repositories {
                maven{
                    url 'http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-custom/'

                    credentials {
                        username 'admin'
                        password 'password'
                    }

                    allowInsecureProtocol = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have found a lot of similar questions but did not find solution for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have found what was the reason. I am an idiot.
I have changed from

```
version '1.0-snapshot'
```

to

```
version '1.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

in Gradle script.